# React component not rendering?

Tags: reactjs, components, jsx

I'm working on a Project for my course, and im using React.js. I have completed my nav portion of the app, and it renders on my local host, but after creating my second component for my hero section. I wrote some code inside the new Hero Component. However, when i go to render the app. The hero component replaces my Nav Portion of the app? What steps did i miss that could cause this problem?

I tried reimporting the components, and it still didn't correct the issue. I am unsure where to go from here.

Comment: It would be good if you can include the relevant code into your post so that we can identify the problem.

Comment: How can we know which steps you missed without seeing your code? So, edit your question and share the code where you think that you missed something.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.